# How to record how long a user has been on an SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like to figure out how to record the amount of time a player has spent on a particular `SKScene`? I want to record this information and then grab the amount of time, add it to `UserDefaults()` and then eventually add it to an `SKLabelNode`.

Should I use `NSTimer`? A point in the right direction would be great!

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement these two methods of SKScene:

Called immediately after the scene has been initialized or decoded.

```
func scene​Did​Load()
```

Called immediately after a scene is removed from a view.

```
func did​Move(to:​ SKView)
```

In each method you can get the current time and then perform the difference.

Comment: `didMove(toView:)` is called immediately after a scene is presented by a view.  The method which is called  immediately before a scene is removed from a view is `willMove(from:)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Will try it out :D